# How to work with the string class in VB: subStrings

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, split, substring

Was not sure the best way to word this question..

This question was before I implemented Data Integration Services, but for the sake of knowledge- I had data from an Excel spreadsheet that needed to be inputted into a database. Example columns are; ID, Name, and Street.

On a webform there are 3 textboxes. The user would copy the ID cell from the Excel spreadsheet, then paste it into the ID textbox of the webform. Then copy the Name cell from the Excel spreadsheet and paste it into the Name textbox of the webform...etc

I am trying to think of a way to be able to copy a whole row from the Excel spreadsheet and paste it into one textbox on the webform.

My first attempt was to Split() the text and create a Dictionary. This did not work because of the spaces between the street address. What is a way that I could break the 1 textbox into 3 subStrings and maintain the integrity and the spaces in the street field? The data type of Name and Street are varchar(30).

```
'Example input of Textbox1.Text "1 myName Cheesecake Factory Lane"
    Dim words As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim split As String() = words.Split(New [Char]() {" "c, ","c, "."c, ":"c, CChar(vbTab)})
    Dim rowData As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For Each s As String In split

        If s.Trim() <> "" Then
          rowData.Add(i, s)
            i += 1
            ' output text for ID would be rowData.Item(0)
            'out text for Name would be rowData.Item(1)
            'out text for Street would be row.Data.Item(2)
        End If
    Next s
```

Comment: _Maintain the spaces in the street field?_  I think this approach is very error-prone since streets can have multiple (or none) spaces, addresses can have multiple (or none) spaces and names could also have spaces.

Comment: Please may I ask, How many fields do you have? Is it only 3 fields per row?

Comment: No that was just to keep things as simple as possible. There are 10 fields.

Comment: Exactly Tim Schmelter, maintaining the integrity is the issue that I am having. I am not going this direction anymore, but surly there has to be a way.

Comment: Hello KRob, excuse me for a minute as I'm not understanding something here, Your saying you did want to get the data from the spreadsheet into textboxes? so how did you get the data from the spreadsheet into the textfield at the top of your code listing? 'Example input of Textbox1.Text "1 myName Cheesecake Factory Lane"

Comment: Zaf, no getting the data into the textbox is not an issue. The data is copied from the spreadsheet into textbox. I included the example input just for an understanding of what data textbox1 may contain.

Answer (score 0):

Excel places several data formats on the clipboard.

The "Text" format delimits the cells with Tab and the rows with Cr. You would have to depend on the users to highlight the proper cells but you can easily split columns using Tab (or rows with vbcrLf.)

Here is some code to explore formats:

```
    Dim o As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
    Dim a() As String = o.GetFormats ' see what formats are available
    Dim x As Object = o.GetData("text") ' returns MemoryStreams so this isn't useful as written

    Dim s As String = Clipboard.GetText ' just get delimited text from Excel
```